# Factor $1-64m^6$ under $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

Factor $1-64m^6$ under $\mathbb{Q}$. We can employ the well known formula: $a^3-b^3 = (a-b)\cdot(a^2+ab+b^2)$.

$1-64m^6 = (1)^3-(4m^2)^3 = (1-4m^2)(1+4m^2+16m^4)=(1+2m)(1-2m)(1+4m^2+16m^4)$.

However, the answer is provided as $(1+2m)(1-2m)(1-2m+4m^2)\cdot(1+2m+4m^2)$.

I cannot understand how it is possible to simplify $(1+4m^2+16m^4)$ to $(1-2m+4m^2)(1+2m+4m^2)$?

Comment: Quick Tip $(m^4+m^2+1) = (m^2-m+1)(m^2+m+1)$

Comment: "Simplify" could also lead to: $\left(1+8m^3\right)\left(1-8m^3\right)$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a simpler approach.  We could first factor $1 - 64m^6$ as a difference of squares, then factoring the resulting sum of cubes and difference of cubes.

\begin{align*}
1 - 64m^6 & = (1 + 8m^3)(1 - 8m^3)\\
          & = (1 + 2m)(1 - 2m + 4m^2)(1 - 2m)(1 + 2m + 4m^2)
\end{align*}

As for your method of first factoring $1 - 64m^3$ as a difference of cubes, we can add and subtract $4m^2$ to the term $1 + 4m^2 + 16m^4$ to form a difference of squares.
\begin{align*}
1 - 64m^6 & = (1 - 4m^2)(1 + 4m^2 + 16m^4)\\
          & = (1 - 4m^2)(1 + 8m^2 + 16m^4 - 4m^2)\\
          & = (1 - 4m^2)[(1 + 4m^2)^2 - 4m^2]\\
          & = (1 + 2m)(1 - 2m)(1 + 4m^2 + 2m)(1 + 4m^2 - 2m)\\
          & = (1 + 2m)(1 - 2m)(1 + 2m + 4m^2)(1 - 2m + 4m^2)
\end{align*}

Answer (score -1):

$$1+4m^2+16m^4$$
$$=1+2\cdot 4m^2+16m^4-4m^2$$
$$=(1+4m^2)^2-(2m)^2$$
$$=(1-2m+4m^2)(1+2m+4m^2)$$

Comment: Hello @unigg. While attempting the question is one part of an answer, please also provide some context and some reasoning to the intuition behind adding and subtracting $4m^2$. OP may not be experienced in this field and may require explanation as to why this particular was chosen.